# Time datatype in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I created a database using rails with `stime` attribute (referring to the starting time). Its type is `Time`. When I added a record with:

```
stime = "10:10"
```

it has been added as:

```
"stime":"2000-0101T10:10:00.000Z"
```

I only want the time, not the date. I thought it's the difference between `Time` and `DateTime`. Could anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation states, it is not.

> Time is an abstraction of dates and times. Time is stored internally
>   as the number of seconds with fraction since the Epoch, January 1,
>   1970 00:00 UTC.

There are several things you can do:

- Store it as a string and do regex validation.
- If you are using Postgres and don't mind depending on it, you can use `time` type. This would allow you do things like: `YourModel.where("stime > '13:00:00'")`.
- Store the time of the day in seconds since midnight. This will require you to add some helper methods for creating and scopes for querying data. You might find ActiveSupport's [extension on numeric values](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#time) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

One way of handling this issue, to exemplify Uzbekjon's third point, is storing the time as seconds since midnight in an integer column:

```
stime = Time.now
# => 2016-04-13 10:58:13 -0700
seconds = stime.seconds_since_midnight.to_i
# => 39493
```

You can then retrieve this value and parse it into the time of day when needed:

```
time = Time.at(seconds).utc
# => 1970-01-01 10:58:13 UTC
result = time.strftime("%I:%M")
# => "10:58"
```

Hope it helps!